# More Efficient Variable from Class

Tags: c#

So I'm writing a simple program for a quiz-like application. I have a Questions class that I set the variables for, but I'm missing an efficient way to define all the questions and call their attributes.

```
Questions question1 = new Questions();
string choice;

public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    question1.ID = 1;
    question1.Question = "My friend _____ 27 years old.";
    question1.AnswerA = "be";
    question1.AnswerB = "is";
    question1.AnswerC = "are";
    question1.AnswerD = "am";
    question1.CorAnswer = "is";
    GenQuestion();
}

private void GenQuestion()
{
    questionLbl.Text = question1.Question;
    aBtn.Text = question1.AnswerA;
    bBtn.Text = question1.AnswerB;
    cBtn.Text = question1.AnswerC;
    dBtn.Text = question1.AnswerD;
}
```

So is there a more efficient way to set the question1 into something else? I'm thinking something like

```
int curQuestion = 1;
questionLbl.Text = question{curQuestion}.Question;
aBtn.Text = question{curQuestion}.AnswerA;
...
curQuestion++;
```

Is this possible? Or will I need to define every Text separately?

Comment: Store them in something and then load the questions in, preferably into an array/list

Comment: Not homework, only personal development, but it is pretty rudimentary. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the questions in a List and then use a ListView with an Object Data source.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Arcaster, welcome, please mark the answer if it helped - so it helps future visitors as well ;). thx.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer... I can't see how using a listview would help a "quiz-like application"

Comment: @Sayse, can you elaborate for me? What would be the best method for what I'm attempting?

Comment: I think it would be better if Anton would elaborate on how their solution would apply.